# MySQL Faster Rand

Tags: mysql

I have a VIEW (view1) that returns random values from another table (Table2) based on values inside Table1.

A trigger is configured to UPDATE a third table (Table3), when values inside Table1 change. The purpose of Table3 is to hold the random values so they don’t get updated all the time.

The problem I have is that each select statement inside the trigger causes the whole row to get new random values for each column being updated. If there are multiple updates than it’s multiple times the whole row is getting new random values. I have adequate hardware, but it’s still too slow. Is there a way to reduce it, so maybe it selects once for each row, regardless of how many columns are receiving the updates? Maybe holds the values somewhere temporarily and updates from that?

Here is sample fiddle. In my real data I have significantly more columns.

Fiddle Example:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4fd8bf89135d8babe8c19fc15a565d50

Currently I don’t have indexes on any columns. I’ve read mixed reviews re indexes and updates.

Lastly, while browsing Stack I found a few links to this: https://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/, but I’m not sure there is a way I can apply it.

Comment: no indexes? add that first. There are some unusual circumstances they make things slower, like when doing a JOIN and reading 50% of a table and small buffers. But for single row updates, you need it.

Comment: index can make a query faster depending on some values but try https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ca2fac8a2bf6cc23d0ec78f787bc0fa  and see if this improves  the queries

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, Ok, I’ll try indexing. Do you have any suggestions on which columns you would index? Seems that a lot of people suggest the WHERE columns.

Comment: @nbk, thanks! I’ll test it now and report back.

Comment: yes. You should for sure index `ID` columns on all tables and probably make them `PRIMARY KEY`, otherwise a hidden primary key column is created.  Then, probably an index for each of the `value` columns on table1.

Comment: @nbk, I’m not seeing changes in the fiddle you linked?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, Great! I’ll test the indexes now and report back.

Comment: hm stramge here show 3 indexes add https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ca2fac8a2bf6cc23d0ec78f787bc0fa

Comment: @nbk, My fault, I didn’t check the table creation statements thoroughly enough. I’m testing the indexing now. Thanks

Comment: @GarrGodfrey (at)nbk, indexing helped. It cut the update time in half. Think there is anything else that can be done?

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but would it be faster to use my trigger to INSERT into Table3 rather than UPDATE/set?

Comment: 5 efficient ways to pick a few random rows:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random ; pick the one that fits your need.

Comment: @RickJames, Are these examples able to be applied to my use case? My RAND isn’t integers and is conditional on multiple columns.

Comment: @aimee - I got lost in your 3 tables, so I cannot address your specific case.  As for 'integer', note the "add a FLOAT" solution depends only on that new column.  Or you could add an AUTO_INCREMENT column to actually get an integer.

Comment: @RickJames - Thanks, I’ll experiment with the add a float solution.